# Test connection to webpage

Tags: c#, http, web

I'm trying to test in my code if a specific web site is available

```
 public override HealthCheckResult DoHealthCheck()
        {


            // Create a request using a URL that can receive a post. 
            var request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(_healthCheckUrl); 
            // Set the Method property of the request to POST.
            request.Method = "GET";
            request.Timeout = HealthCheckConfiguration.Timeout * 1000;\\Very Very large timeout
            // Set the ContentType property of the WebRequest.
            request.ContentType = "text/xml; encoding='utf-8'";
            // Get the response.
            try
            {
                HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
                //var response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
                if (response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK)
                {
                    return HealthCheckResult.Success;

                }
            }
            catch (WebException)
            {
                  return HealthCheckResult.Timeout;
            }
            return HealthCheckResult.Failed;
        }
```

Sometimes I get the HttpStatusCode.OK but most of the times I get the timeout exception.
If I just copy paste the _healthCheckUrl string in internet explorer the page is always loaded successfully very quickly.  I don't understand why in the code i get so much timeouts.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The code seems to assume that *any* `WebException` is a timeout.  Is that the actual exception being thrown?  When this occurs, what are the details of the `WebException` being caught?  (Hint: Never ignore exceptions.  They are trying to tell you what's wrong.)

Comment: You seem to always assume WebException is a Timeout - examine it for details?

Comment: You are right, the code is not clear, but the exception is indeed timeout, please see the exception attached:

System.Net.WebException was caught
  HResult=-2146233079
  Message=The operation has timed out
  Source=System
  StackTrace:
       at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetResponse()
       at DoHealthCheck() in line 186
  InnerException:

Comment: If your URI is not valid you will receive System.UriFormatException , whicj will be not be handled in your code...

Comment: The URI is valid for sure in my specific test, But I will modify the code to test all exceptions types